# module.getProviderByKey(providerKey).instance returns the instance without injecting its dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I have a class called `PermissionManager` that receives a list of `Voter` interfaces in the constructor.

```ts
    export interface Voter {
        vote(): bool;
    }

    export class PermissionManager {
          constructor(private readonly voters: Voter[]) {
          }
    }

    export class SpecificVoter implements Voter {
          constructor(private readonly anotherDependency: AnotherDependency) {
          }

          public function vote(): bool {
              return true;
          }
    }
```

The idea is that `PermissionManager` shouldn't know what the voters are. So, to do so, I add each of my voters into a global list so that when I instantiate `PermissionManager`, it has the list of all the voters. Basically, I'm doing something similar to [Symfony's service tags](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html).

Here's my NestJS provider:

```ts
    const provider = {
      provide: PermissionManager,
      useFactory: (container: ModulesContainer) => {

        const voters = [];

        globalList.forEach(value => {
          container.forEach(module => {
            const provider = module.getProviderByKey(value.constructor.name);

            if (provider !== undefined) {
              voters.push(provider.instance);
            }
          });
        });

        return new PermissionManager(voters);
      },
      inject: [ModulesContainer],
    };
```

The provider can properly find the class `SpecificVoter` but it never instantiates its dependencies.

Therefore, why doesn't `module.getProviderByKey(SpecificVoter).instance` return `SpecificVoter` with its dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've found a way to make this work but it seems hacky.

Basically, it seems like the provider will return the class instance from the `.instance` property but not the dependencies until a certain promise is completed. So, we have to wait for that promise to complete to get the appropriate instance.

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
{
      provide: PermissionManager,
      useFactory: (container: ModulesContainer) => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          const promises = [];
          const voters = [];

          globalList.forEach(value => {
            container.forEach(module => {
              const provider = module.getProviderByKey(value.constructor.name);

              if (provider !== undefined) {
                promises.push(new Promise(resolve1 => {
                  // This following code seems to be a hack for now and should be modified when
                  // something official replaces it
                  provider.getInstanceByContextId(STATIC_CONTEXT).donePromise.then(value1 => {
                    voters.push(provider.instance);
                    resolve1();
                  });
                }));
              }
            });
          });

          Promise.all(promises).then(value => {
            resolve(new PermissionManager(voters));
            return;
          });
        });
      },
      inject: [ModulesContainer],
    };
```